# How can I use LoadLibrary to get the address of a function defined in fileapi.h?

Tags: winapi, fileapi, loadlibrary

I want to know the name of the DLL/LIB in which functions declared in `fileapi.h` are kept.

So that I can use `LoadLibrary(dllname)` (if it is inside DLL).

Comment: It's in the Microsoft documentation. Usually the easiest thing to do is google the function name.

Comment: Hi @simplePerson43, is that the answer solves your issue? You could feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it if it does help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [fileapi.h header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/) documentation lists the functions, and their individual documentations all say the same thing - the functions are implemented in `kernel32.dll`.  Which you don't need to use `LoadLibrary()` for, you can use `GetModuleHandle()` instead, since `kernel32.dll` is loaded by default in all processes.

To get the address of a function in a loaded DLL module, you need to use `GetProcAddress()`, giving it an `HMODULE` from `LoadLibrary/Ex()` or `GetModuleHandle()`.